# Typed.js initialize with existing text and then loop it

Tags: typed.js

I'm working with typed.js to get some words typed. I would like the first word to be showing when the page loads and start the loop from there. In order to get this result I've just placed "nice" in between the span tags, did this the trick.

But... When looking to the following codepen, you can see that the first loop is correct. When the second loop starts, the first word (nice) is not being typed but just appears and disappears quickly. I could really use some help to fix this. Any thoughts?

```js
var typewriter = $('.typewriter');

  if(typewriter.length) {

    function initTypewriter() {

     var typed = new Typed(".typewriter", {
        strings: $(".typewriter").attr("data-typewriter").split("|").map(function(e) {
          return e
        }),
        typeSpeed: 80,
        backSpeed: 75,
        startDelay: 1000,
        backDelay: 2000,
        loop: !0,
        loopcount: false,
        showCursor: false,
        callback: function(e){ } // call function after typing is done
        });
    };

    initTypewriter();

  };
```

```html
<h2>A <span title="nice, clean, good" class="typewriter" data-typewriter="nice|clean|good">nice</span> example</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.6/typed.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/Dansbeer/pen/geGbgB?editors=1111)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is over 2 years old now, but I came across this issue today and couldn't find a solution either so put together a workaround.

Essentially, create 2 instances of Typed JS.

The first removes the existing text and uses the onComplete method to remove itself, clear the text content from the DOM and then setup the second instance to do the actual loop.

My example has no dependencies outside of Typed JS, but you could adapt to jQuery selectors, etc, pretty easily.

Demo here: https://codepen.io/jneale/pen/pogyzXK

HTML

```html
<h1>Hello <span class="typed-replaced">world</span></h1>
```

Javascript

```js
function setupTypedReplace() {
  // the text node to type in
  var typed_class = 'typed-replaced';

  // the original text content to replace, but also use
  var replace_text = 'world';

  var options = {
    strings: ['there', 'buddy', replace_text], // existing text goes at the end
    typeSpeed: 80,
    backSpeed: 60,
    backDelay: 1000,
    loop: true,
    smartBackspace: false,
    cursorChar: '_',
    attr: null
  };

  // clear out the existing text gracefully then setup the loop
  new Typed('.' + typed_class, {
    strings: [replace_text, ''],
    backSpeed: options.backSpeed,
    backDelay: options.backDelay,
    cursorChar: options.cursorChar,
    attr: options.attr,
    startDelay: 700,
    onComplete: function (t) {
      // existing text has now been removed so let's actually clear everything out
      // and setup the proper Typed loop we want. If we don't do this, the original
      // text content breaks the flow of the loop.
      t.destroy();
      document.getElementsByClassName(typed_class)[0].textContent = '';
      new Typed('.' + typed_class, options);
    }
  });
}

setupTypedReplace();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to dig around the [Typed.js repo](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js), but I finally figured out a workaround. Put the first element inside the HTML tag, and then reset the position after the loop is finished using `onLastStringBackspaced`.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  var typed = new Typed('#element', {
    strings: ['And this is Item 2'],
    loop: true,
    typeSpeed: 50,
    smartBackspace: false,
    backDelay: 1200,
    backSpeed: 30,
    onLastStringBackspaced: () => typed.strPos = 0 // set position to 0
  });
}, 750)
```

```html
<!-- Element to contain animated typing -->
<span id="element">This is Item 1</span>

 <!-- Load library from the CDN -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typed.js@2.0.16/dist/typed.umd.js"></script>
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/cviyubag-the-selector/pen/xxmYeRQ)